# Can't print using Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I'm trying it for some hours and can't get a good result. I need to print a PDF document by the command line and I chose Ghostscript to do the hard work. I'm creating a file named **config.cfg** with my parameters and passing it to Ghostscript. My Ghostscript installation path is `C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.15\bin` and I'm using the executable `gswin64c` for the tests. My configuration file is the following:

**config.cfg**

```
"C:\pdf\pdf\type_theory.pdf"
-colour
-noquery
-printer "Work Printer"
-ghostscript "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.15\bin\gswin64c.exe"
-all
-portrait
-copies 1
```

and I'm calling, via command line:

```
gswin64c -config "C:\\pdf\\pdf\\config.cfg"
```

But I'm receiving the following error in output:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.15 (2014-09-22)
Copyright (C) 2014 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Error: /undefined in C:\\pdf\\pdf\\postscript.cfg
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1188/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
```

I can understand that it is missing a file by its last sentence, but I can't figure what it is. Can somebody help me to find my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't selected a device, so you'll get the default device, which is the display. If you want to print to a printer, you will need the mswinpr2 device. So -sDEVICE=mswinpr2

I'm not at all sure where you got the contents of config.cfg, is this supposed to be a command line for gsprint by any chance ? The options make some sense for gsprint, they don't make any sense at all for Ghostscript. Ghostscript switches are mostly either -s or -d there are comparatively few which are simply -

The error doesn't tell you its missing a file, that would be 'undefinedfilename' its telling you that something in 'postscript.cgfg' is undefined. PostScript is a programming language, and this is the interpreter telling you your program has an error. -color is probably the problem.

Comment: I was doing a mistake. I was following this: <http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/gsview/gsprint.htm> and I didn't ever see that it wasn't exactly for GhostScript, but for GSPrint.